# NEXTJS getting 404 in production but working fine locally

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

This happened when I added conditional logic in the _app.tsx folder to render the sidebar if its not the path is not sign-in or register, together with this i added a redirect in my middleware the redirects to sign-in if the user is not authed. I didn't commit frequently so I don't really know what caused this issue.

The first issue was a hydration error, after I removed the conditional rendering in _app.tsx that stopped that error but I'm still getting the 404

the 404 is coming from the `<Component {...pageprops}/>`
on "/" the sidebar renders fine with all the data from the db but the actual page is returning a 404

[Github repo](https://github.com/bentoodev/crm-grow)

[Production site](https://crmgrow.bentoo.dev)

feel free to clone it to test locally